# Is cudaDeviceSynchronize() required before cudaFree()?

Tags: memory-management, cuda

CUDA version 10.1. Pascal GPU. All commands are issued to the default stream:

```cpp
void * ptr;
cudaMalloc(&ptr, ...);

launch_kernel<<<...>>>(ptr);

cudaDeviceSynchronize();     // Is this required?
cudaFree(ptr);
```

Does the answer change with `cudaMallocManaged()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some CUDA API calls such as `cudaMalloc(), cudaFree(), cudaHostAlloc()`, device to device copies etc. change the virtual memory address mapping of GPU. These calls are causing device synchronization, so that you don't need to call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` because it is already synchronizing.

The same happens with the `cudaMallocManaged()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need that. You can find it in the offical [CUDA Programming Guide :: **Appendix F. Stream Ordered Memory Allocator**](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#stream-ordered-memory-allocator-intro), the first line:

> Managing memory allocations using `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` causes GPU to synchronize across all executing CUDA streams.