# Is synchronization required before releasing device memory back to an allocator?

Tags: cuda

When dealing with some CUDA runtime api calls for memory management like cudaFree, explicit synchronization is not neccessary. [Is cudaDeviceSynchronize() required before cudaFree()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070326/is-cudadevicesynchronize-required-before-cudafree)

Now, assume that instead of CUDA api calls, a user-defined allocator object is used to allocate and deallocate device memory.

```
template<class Alloc>
void reduce(Alloc& alloc, ...){
    size_t   temp_storage_bytes = 0;
    cub::DeviceReduce::Sum(nullptr, temp_storage_bytes, d_in, d_out, num_items);

    void* d_temp_storage = alloc.allocate(temp_storage_bytes);

    cub::DeviceReduce::Sum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_in, d_out, num_items);

    //synchronize before deallocate?

    alloc.deallocate(d_temp_storage);
}
```

Should explicit synchronization be used before deallocate?
Must explicit synchronization be used before deallocate?

Is there a possible implementation of the allocator which can cause problems if the memory is still in use by a kernel at the point of calling deallocate?

For example, in the linked question, the argument for implicit synchronization is the modification of virtual address space.
Would above code sample break if, e.g. the allocator is implemented using driver-side virtual memory management https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/introducing-low-level-gpu-virtual-memory-management/ , and deallocate would just unmap the physical memory from the virtual address range, but keeping the virtual adress range intact.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Your user defined allocator must at some point call CUDA provided malloc and free, right? So the heuristics of blocking and synchronizing around malloc and free will apply to your allocator, won't it?

Comment: @talonmies I added some more thoughts. I think the main question should be whether there is an allocator implementation which could break the code without explicit synchronization